# Creating two different timer using Android Chronometer

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse

I wanted to create a two countdown timer that will run at the same time in one android application using chronometer. is it possible? if you have some tutorials please comment it in here I will gladly appreciate it. thank you :)

Comment: if they run at the same time, why do you need 2 of them?

Comment: I'm trying to create a basketball scoreboard, so I need one for Game time and one for the shot clock

Comment: and what issue are you facing for specifically using 2 at the same time?

Comment: I don't know any method how to do that. I'm thinking that if I use the count function it'll crash.